# Multiple Checkboxes and enumeration

Tags: c#, checkbox, enumeration

I am having troubles getting my head wrapped around how this should be done. 
I have 3 check boxes on a form that are to be input into a constructor.  I am creating a variable to pass this information into the constructor.  Listed below some of the code

```
public enum Accessories
    {
        None,
        StereoSystem,
        LeatherInterior,
        StereoAndLeather,
        ComputerNavigation,
        StereoAndNavigation,
        LeatherAndNavigation,
        All
    }

        SalesQuote.Accessories accessoryChosen;

        if(!chkStereoSystem.Checked && !chkLeatherInterior.Checked && !chkComputerNavigation.Checked)
            {
                accessoryChosen = SalesQuote.Accessories.None;
            }
            else if(chkStereoSystem.Checked && !chkLeatherInterior.Checked && !chkComputerNavigation.Checked)
            {
                accessoryChosen = SalesQuote.Accessories.StereoSystem;
            }
```

Am sure there is an much cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Looking at your logic, you should be using radio buttons instead. Do you intend for people to select more than one option?

Comment: Also do assign bit flag values to the enums: None=0, Stereo=1 leather=2, stereo&leather=3 etc. Then you can do simple arithemtic with them..

Comment: Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should explicitly set the flag values:

```
public enum Accessories
{
    None = 0,
    StereoSystem = 1,
    LeatherInterior = 2,
    StereoAndLeather = 3,
    ComputerNavigation = 4,
    StereoAndNavigation = 5,
    LeatherAndNavigation = 6,
    All = 7
}
```

Now you can calculate the chosen accessories like this:

```
Accessories accessoryChosen = (Accessories) 
 ((chkStereoSystem.Checked ? 1 : 0)  +
  (chkLeatherInterior.Checked ? 2 : 0) +          
  (chkComputerNavigation.Checked ? 4 : 0) ) ;
```

Here the flag values would be the same without writing them out, but this should be done for clarity!

**Update:** As Nadia points out the `Enum` need not enumerate **all** combinations.

If more Accessories come up this would get really awkward.

Let's add just two more

```
WarpDrive = 8,
FluxCompensator = 16,
```

This would bring up the number of combinations up to 32! Ouch!

Instead leave the **combinations** either all out  or include only a few really important combinations as the [link in Nadia's comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) advises.

Now you will need to **query** for an Accessory. Using bitwise arithmetic you can write a helper function:

```
bool Has(Accessories Chosen, Accessories Target)
{
    return (Chosen & Target) != Accessories.None;
}
```

or, assuming they are sitting in a class `Order` or `Car` you can add a class function:

```
bool Has(Accessories Target)
{
    return (this.ChosenAccessories & Target) != Accessories.None;
}
```

You can also add the `[FlagsAttribute]` if you want the combinations to show nice lists of their values when displayed as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You may make your enum flags, and then you won't have to have all combinations in the enum, but instead use | to combine then in a variable:

```
[Flags]public enum Accessories
{
    None=0,
    StereoSystem = 1,
    LeatherInterior =2,
    //StereoAndLeather = StereoSystem | LeatherInterior ,
    ComputerNavigation = 4,
    //StereoAndNavigation = StereoSystem | ComputerNavigation ,
    //LeatherAndNavigation = LeatherInterior | ComputerNavigation,
    All =  StereoSystem | LeatherInterior | ComputerNavigation
}

accessoryChosen =  Accessories.None;
if(chkStereoSystem.Checked )
       accessoryChosen |= Accessories.StereoSystem ;//You can add all flags this way, accessoryChosen will contain them all


if( (accessoryChosen & Accessories.StereoSystem) == Accessories.StereoSystem) 
    ...//StereoSystem was chosen
```

Thus if you'll have to add some new types of accessories, you'll have all additional combinations automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the RadioButton's Tag Property (assuming Papa's comment is right)

In the constructor of the form:

```
    chkStereoSystem.Tag = Accesories.StereoSystem;
    chkLeatherInterior.Tag = Accesories.LeatherInterior;
    chkComputerNavigation.Tag = Accesories.ComputerNavigation;
```

And whenever you need the selected one:

```
 SalesQuote.Accessories accessoryChosen =(Accessories) yourForm.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                  .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Tag;
```

If no RadioButton was selected, FirstOrDefault will return 0, it will give you the first element of the enum: `None`