# Organizing elements of a instance inside a class property

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class of clients of a library and each client can have four favourite genres: Adventure, Romance, Police and Sci-Fi.

For example now I have a property of the class defined as a structure.

```
public struct PrefGenres
{
    public bool adventure, romance, police, scifi;
}
```

Before a create a new element of the Client class, I create a new struct of PrefGenres and define all the elements to false and after the reading of the user selected checkboxes I change to true the genres selected by him.

Then I send it as a parameter to the Client instance.
That I want to know is if there are better ways to do this, and if there are, how do I code it?

I've been thinking of using a enum but it turned into a real pain to check the values. The only way I've seen it was to get the enum as a string and then see if inside that string there are the genres one by one.

I DON'T WANT VECTORS! THAT'S WAY TO EASY!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By vectors I assume you mean an array or list? Thats too easy because....? Also, have you considered using a `Flags` enum?

Comment: Have you thought of flags? Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400378/multiple-checkboxes-and-enumeration/28400655#28400655

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes. I'm tired of them. I want some other hard things.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I've not learnt flags yet but I will try that now. Looks easy.

Comment: Ummm... just because something is "easy" doesn't make it the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @DiogoMartinho it is easy, just make sure all the constants are powers of two (2,4, 8 and so on) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx look here for more details

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you're right sir, but I want challenges :)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I've though using integers numbers being passed to a class and then converting them to binary. 16 options, 16 numers...

Comment: @DiogoMartinho apparently, you weren't the first one to think about it, flags have been there since framework 1.1

Comment: Also `IGenre` and `abstract Genre` (though I suppose neither allow multiples).

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova yes but I have never work with them, I will give it a try.

Comment: @BradChristie might be something I will look up in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @DiogoMartinho it was my way to say that you were heading in the right direction :) Actually you can use bitwise operations with all integral types, not only enums (in fact, it works with enums only because they're not much more than their underlying types), but using flags is a more civilized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that an `enum` consisting of flags, in combination a few small helper extension methods would make for a clean and easy solution.

Such as:

```
namespace TryOuts
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [Flags]
    public enum PreferedGenres
    {
        None = 0,
        Adventure = 1,
        Romance = 2,
        Police = 4,
        SciFi = 8
    }

    public static class PreferedGenresExtensions
    {
        public static PreferedGenres AddPreference(this PreferedGenres current, PreferedGenres toAdd)
        {
            return current | toAdd;
        }
        public static PreferedGenres RemovePreference(this PreferedGenres current, PreferedGenres toRemove)
        {
            return current & ~(toRemove);
        }
        public static IEnumerable<PreferedGenres> GetSelectedPreferences(this PreferedGenres genres)
        {
            foreach (PreferedGenres g in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PreferedGenres)))
                if (genres.HasFlag(g) && g != PreferedGenres.None)
                    yield return g;
        }
        public static IEnumerable<PreferedGenres> GetSelectablePrefences(this PreferedGenres genres)
        {
            foreach (PreferedGenres g in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PreferedGenres)))
                if (!genres.HasFlag(g))
                    yield return g;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            var myPreferences = PreferedGenres
                .None
                .AddPreference(PreferedGenres.SciFi)
                .AddPreference(PreferedGenres.Adventure);
            Console.WriteLine("My preferences:");
            foreach (var p in myPreferences.GetSelectedPreferences())
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            Console.WriteLine("Available for selection:");
            foreach (var p in myPreferences.GetSelectablePrefences())
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list of strings, so that you don't have to change code in multiple places when you need to support more preferences.

Not sure what you mean here:

> I DON'T WANT VECTORS! THAT'S WAY TO EASY!

"A solution should be as simple as it can be, but no simpler." Apologies to Einstein

Comment: KISS stands for keep it simple stupid.
Sorry, I don't go along with that kind of things :)

Comment: @DiogoMartinho I sincerely hope I never have to deal with your production code. Making things harder or more complex just because you can just leads to more work/trouble/bugs down the road.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET challenging things are the things I actually like. That's just my way of being.

Comment: @DiogoMartinho Clearly you aren't going to agree with me, but please do try to learn how to do things *right*, not just "complex". And simpler is almost *always* better. This coming from someone who really does do this for a living.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I believe you sir. I do things as simple as possible. The way I've made the struct is simple, I just wanted some new ideas on how to make this, things I didn't knew, for example the flags. I've never worked with them, and in my POV a struct is way easier than a flag. I just, can't stop learning new ways of doing things that's the main reason on this post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with C# or classical OOP languages, but i think you have a blurred idea of what an enum can give you.

You are creating an enum of boolean values, i think it should look more like this:

```
//taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx 
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
//in your case:
enum PrefGenres = {adventure, romance, police, scifi}
```

in the Model, Person, would look something like:

In your model (Client), should look something

```
var person = new Person();
person.name = "André";
Person.prefGenres = new Array( PrefGenres.adventure, PrefGenres.romance );
```

I don't know what the syntax for Arrays or collections or whatever C# uses in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe creating a class with foud properties:

```
public class Genres()
{
    public bool Adventure {get;set;}
    public bool Romance {get;set;}
    public bool Police {get;set;}
    public bool Scifi {get;set;}
}
```

and inside your Person, something like:

```
public class Person()
{
    public string Name {get;set}
    public Genres PrefGenres {get;set;}
}
```

and then only like:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.PrefGenres = new Genres() { 
Adventure = False,
Romance = True,
Police = False,
Scifi = False
 };
```

:)

Comment: that was also an idea but I though a struct would be shorter than that. the only thing I actually regret is that the structure can't have default values when declared, on the other hand a instance of a class can! still, thank you!